# cannot install with yarn, but can do with npm

Tags: npm, npm-install, yarnpkg, openbsd

NB : first time I install a massive project with yarn/npm. Please forgive if I miss stuff.

I am trying to install PeerTube on OpenBSD. There is no official port or work yet, but it runs fine in FreeBSD apparently.

Trouble is that I cannot run yarn there.

```
yarn install --production --pure-lockfile
yarn install v1.12.3
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
warning Resolution field "@types/bluebird@3.5.21" is incompatible with requested version "@types/bluebird@3.5.18"
[3/5] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.4: The platform "openbsd" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.4" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[4/5] Linking dependencies...
[5/5] Building fresh packages...
[1/7] ⠂ bcrypt
[6/7] ⠂ deasync
[7/7] ⠄ youtube-dl
[4/7] ⠄ rdf-canonize
error /var/www/peertube/versions/peertube-v1.0.1/node_modules/bcrypt: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
Arguments: 
Directory: /var/www/peertube/versions/peertube-v1.0.1/node_modules/bcrypt
Output:
node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.9.1
node-pre-gyp info using node@8.12.0 | openbsd | x64
node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/var/www/peertube/versions/peertube-v1.0.1/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node" (not found)
node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v2.0.1/bcrypt_lib-v2.0.1-node-v57-openbsd-x64-unknown.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp http 404 https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v2.0.1/bcrypt_lib-v2.0.1-node-v57-openbsd-x64-unknown.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v2.0.1/bcrypt_lib-v2.0.1-node-v57-openbsd-x64-unknown.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@2.0.1 and node@8.12.0 (node-v57 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp http 404 status code downloading tarball https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v2.0.1/bcrypt_lib-v2.0.1-node-v57-openbsd-x64-unknown.tar.gz 
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@8.12.0 | openbsd | x64
gyp info ok 
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@8.12.0 | openbsd | x64
gyp info spawn /usr/local/bin/python2
gyp info spawn args [ '/var/www/peertube/versions/peertube-v1.0.1/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/var/www/peertube/versions/peertube-v1.0.1/node_modules/bcrypt/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/var/www/peertube/versions/peertube-v1.0.1/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/stephane/.node-gyp/8.12.0/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/stephane/.node-gyp/8.12.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/var/www/peertube/versions/peertube-v1.0.1/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/stephane/.node-gyp/8.12.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/var/www/peertube/versions/peertube-v1.0.1/node_modules/bcrypt',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
gyp info ok 
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@8.12.0 | openbsd | x64
gypgmake: Entering directory '/var/www/peertube/versions/peertube-v1.0.1/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
 info   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
spawn gmake
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=gnu++0x"
gmake: *** [bcrypt_lib.target.mk:105: Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o] Error 1
gmake: Leaving directory '/var/www/peertube/versions/peertube-v1.0.1/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gmake` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/var/www/peertube/versions/peertube-v1.0.1/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System OpenBSD 6.4
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/var/www/peertube/versions/peertube-v1.0.1/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/var/www/peertube/versions/peertube-v1.0.1/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=/var/www/peertube/versions/peertube-v1.0.1/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding" "--napi_version=3" "--node_abi_napi=napi"
gyp ERR! cwd /var/www/peertube/versions/peertube-v1.0.1/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v8.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /var/www/peertube/versions/peertube-v1.0.1/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/var/www/peertube/versions/peertube-v1.0.1/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/var/www/peertube/versions/peertube-v1.0.1/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/var/www/peertube/versions/peertube-v1.0.1/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System OpenBSD 6.4
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/var/www/peertube/versions/peertube-v1.0.1/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /var/www/peertube/versions/peertube-v1.0.1/node_modules/bcrypt
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v8.12.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.9.1
node-pre-gyp ERR! not
```

I see the thing blocks at bcrypt. So if I try to install bcrypt using npm, it works fine (or so I understand). But not with yarn itself still.

```
npm add bcrypt                               

> bcrypt@2.0.1 install /var/www/peertube/versions/peertube-v1.0.1/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v2.0.1/bcrypt_lib-v2.0.1-node-v57-openbsd-x64-unknown.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@2.0.1 and node@8.12.0 (node-v57 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
gmake: Entering directory '/var/www/peertube/versions/peertube-v1.0.1/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
  /usr/bin/clang++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=bcrypt_lib' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DBUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION' -I/home/stephane/.node-gyp/8.12.0/include/node -I/home/stephane/.node-gyp/8.12.0/src -I/home/stephane/.node-gyp/8.12.0/deps/openssl/config -I/home/stephane/.node-gyp/8.12.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/home/stephane/.node-gyp/8.12.0/deps/uv/include -I/home/stephane/.node-gyp/8.12.0/deps/zlib -I/home/stephane/.node-gyp/8.12.0/deps/v8/include -I../node_modules/nan  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -I/usr/local/include -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -std=gnu++0x -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o ../src/blowfish.cc
  /usr/bin/clang++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=bcrypt_lib' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DBUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION' -I/home/stephane/.node-gyp/8.12.0/include/node -I/home/stephane/.node-gyp/8.12.0/src -I/home/stephane/.node-gyp/8.12.0/deps/openssl/config -I/home/stephane/.node-gyp/8.12.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/home/stephane/.node-gyp/8.12.0/deps/uv/include -I/home/stephane/.node-gyp/8.12.0/deps/zlib -I/home/stephane/.node-gyp/8.12.0/deps/v8/include -I../node_modules/nan  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -I/usr/local/include -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -std=gnu++0x -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt.o ../src/bcrypt.cc
  /usr/bin/clang++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=bcrypt_lib' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DBUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION' -I/home/stephane/.node-gyp/8.12.0/include/node -I/home/stephane/.node-gyp/8.12.0/src -I/home/stephane/.node-gyp/8.12.0/deps/openssl/config -I/home/stephane/.node-gyp/8.12.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/home/stephane/.node-gyp/8.12.0/deps/uv/include -I/home/stephane/.node-gyp/8.12.0/deps/zlib -I/home/stephane/.node-gyp/8.12.0/deps/v8/include -I../node_modules/nan  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -I/usr/local/include -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -std=gnu++0x -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o ../src/bcrypt_node.cc
  /usr/bin/clang++ -shared -pthread -rdynamic -m64 -Wl,-z,wxneeded  -Wl,-soname=bcrypt_lib.node -o Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib.node -Wl,--start-group Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt.o Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o -Wl,--end-group 
  rm -rf "Release/bcrypt_lib.node" && cp -pPRf "Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib.node" "Release/bcrypt_lib.node"
  rm -rf "/var/www/peertube/versions/peertube-v1.0.1/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node" && cp -pPRf "Release/bcrypt_lib.node" "/var/www/peertube/versions/peertube-v1.0.1/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node"
  touch Release/obj.target/action_after_build.stamp
gmake: Leaving directory '/var/www/peertube/versions/peertube-v1.0.1/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
+ bcrypt@2.0.1
added 69 packages from 47 contributors and audited 6805 packages in 31.925s
found 3 vulnerabilities (2 low, 1 critical)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Would be cool if I managed already to setup bcrypt using yarn, no ? First step on the path. What am I missing ?

Comment: Actually, I managed to install bcrypt globally using yarn:     

yarn list|grep bcrypt
warning Resolution field "@types/bluebird@3.5.21" is incompatible with requested version "@types/bluebird@3.5.18"
├─ @types/bcrypt@2.0.0
├─ bcrypt-pbkdf@1.0.2
├─ bcrypt@2.0.1
│  ├─ bcrypt-pbkdf@^1.0.0

But I still cannot install the rest of the project locally.

Comment: you might want to contact peertube devs on irc : IRC : #peertube on chat.freenode.net:6697